# yii2 : how to pass data on link click from one page to another

Tags: php, yii2

In yii2 I am trying to pass data on link click from one page to another. And for this I am using POST as following:-

```
Html::a('link-name', ['/url/place-details?id='.$place_id], [
  'data'=>[
         'method' => 'post',
         'params'=>['place'=>json_encode($place)],
    ]])
```

This is working fine when I click the link first time, the post request contains all the required data. But if I refresh the page (or go to another page and then click back from browser) this post data is lost. And following error message is displayed:-

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException Undefined index: place

As the request now doesn't contain the posted data. How can I resolve this and create a request that perserve data along the sessions. I have tried passing data through sessions but same issue persists.

Following is the controller action that handles the requested URL:-

```
public function actionPlaceDetails($id=null)
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $data = $request->post('place');
    $place = json_decode($data);
    return $this->render('place',['place'=>$place]);
}
```

Comment: what does `$place` contains?

Comment: $place is an array and I am converting it to json before passing. I need the whole array contents on next page

Comment: @savina post your controller action

Comment: update you question add  the code for the controller action involved  in the part of code you have posted above.

Comment: I have added the controller action in my question.

Comment: First of all use Yii::$app->request->post('place') instead of $_POST['place']. How to use sessions read here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#access-session-data

Comment: I want to achieve this without the use of sessions. As storing post data into sessions is also resulting to similar issue

Comment: obviously it will not work at when you refresh a page, because it will lose post data.Why session not work for you??